SQL Job runs slow after reindex (and adding/removing SET ARITHABORT ON)
I have a SQL 2019 Server that is a multi-tenanted environment, so I've got lots of identical (apart from the data) customer databases on it.
There is a need to aggregate some data every 30 minutes in each of these databases, so there's a SQL job that runs in a separate database and creates a table of customer database names to loop through and then generates some dynamic SQL to run against each one in turn. I've omitted the generation of the DB names but this is the code that loops:
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME,
        @EndTime DATETIME,
        @EnterpriseId INT,
        @Error NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @AutoId = MIN(AutoId) FROM @DBs;

WHILE @AutoId IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @DatabaseName = DatabaseName, @EnterpriseId = EnterpriseId, @DatabaseId = DatabaseId FROM @DBs WHERE AutoId = @AutoId

    IF @DatabaseId IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY
            SET @dynSql = 'USE ' + @DatabaseName + ';';
            SET @dynSql = @dynSql +  'EXEC Nightly_CustomerRewards_TransactionEntry_Update;';
            
            SET @StartTime = GETDATE();
            PRINT @dynSql;
            EXEC(@dynSql)
            SET @EndTime = GETDATE();
            
            UPDATE dbo.Enterprise SET AggregationsDuration = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartTime, @EndTime) WHERE EnterpriseId = @EnterpriseId
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
           SELECT @Error = CONCAT(@DatabaseName,': ', ERROR_MESSAGE(), ' In ' , ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ' at ' , FORMAT(ERROR_LINE(), 'N0')) 
           PRINT @Error;
        END CATCH
    END

    SELECT @AutoId = MIN(AutoId) FROM @DBs WHERE AutoId > @AutoId
END


When the job was implemented (on a Monday), it completed in about 30 seconds and didn't have any significant impact on the CPU of the server, and it continued this way for the rest of the week. In the early hours of Sunday morning, the DB reindex ran and after that point the job then took around 2 minutes to complete and there was a huge spike in the CPU.
After much googling, I found something that mentioned setting "SET ARITHABORT ON" in the SQL job. I did this and hey presto the job went back to 30 seconds and no CPU pressure.
Fast forward to the next Sunday and after the reindex ran again, the same thing happened again - the job went back to running slowly and the CPU spikes re-occurred. I commented out the "SET ARITHABORT ON" line and once again it went back to running quickly with no CPU pressure.
It's been like this for the past few weeks where I have to add in/remove the arithabort statement after every reindex depending on what the last state was!
Has anyone got any suggestions as to what is causing this and how I can fix it?
Thanks

Did the DB reindex ran on the separate database or the customer databases?

As an FYI, there's no need for dynamic SQL here. You could just do: DECLARE @ProcName nvarchar(776) = QUOTENAME(DatabaseName) + N'.dbo.Nightly_CustomerRewards_TransactionEntry_Update'; EXEC @ProcName;.

Why are you rebuilding the indexes anyway? The statistics update is probably happening asynchronously after the rebuild, so the procedure doesn't have time to pick up the new statistics. What is the result of select name, is_auto_update_stats_on, is_auto_update_stats_async_on from sys.databases

Note that SET ARITHABORT is a myth, all it does is force a recompilation. You could just as easily do sp_recompile 'YourProcName'

@Izanagi - just the Customer databases

@ThomA - I don't see why that would make a difference but I can give it a try

@Charlieface - indexes are rebuilt once a week across all tables using Ola Hallegren's scripts. Why is that a bad idea?
The output from your query is 1 for is_auto_update_stats_on and 0 for is_auto_update_stats_async_on for all databases.

Depends what settings you are using on those scripts. The default options are far too aggressive IMO if you have SSD drives. You shouldn't worry about fragmentation until it gets pretty high, over 50% I would think. Anyway, just add EXEC sp_recompile N'YourProc' on the end of the index job and that should sort it out.

It eliminates the injection vulnerability in your code, @markjerrom .

@Charlieface, these are the setting we use:
EXEC dbo.IndexOptimize
Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y',
MinNumberOfPages = 1000,
FragmentationLevel1 = 30,
FragmentationLevel2 = 50,
LogToTable = 'Y',
TimeLimit = 25200
Presumably I'm going to have to loop through all the databases and run that recompile statement against each of them?

@Charlieface, just another thought after I posted that last comment:
Am I recompiling the stored procedure in the separate database that then calls each database in turn or I'm going to have to loop through all the databases and run that recompile statement against each of them for the called procedure?

Loop through all databases. See https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb

thanks @Charlieface, I've added the recompile as additional job steps so will see if it has an effect. What I still don't understand is why it's happening?

Like I said: after the rebuild the procedure need to be recompiled, but for whatever reason you are getting a bad plan, possibly because of out of date statistics. You need to investigate why that bad plan is even possible, you need to give the server an obviously very good plan so that the bad plan won't even be considered. Without any further info (procedure code, relevant tables and indexes, and the plans) we can't help you further.

@Charlieface - the reindex ran, I marked those procedures for recompile and exactly the same thing happened, the job went back to running slowly with high CPU. I've put the 'SET ARITHABORT ON' statement back into the job step and it's started running quickly wiht low CPU once more ... any suggestions now?

@Charlieface, I'm adding them to the job step that calls the stored procedure - when the re-indexing is being done nothing is being altered.

They aren't added - job runs fine
Reindexing runs - job runs slow
Add in ARITHABORT to the job step - job runs fine
Reindexing runs - job runs slow
Remove ARITHABORT - job runs fine

etc, etc ...

I see. Yes that was what I originally thought. Again: we cannot help without further info. I keep asking for basic debugging info: the procedure/job code, the relevant tables and indexes, and the fast and slow plans. I'm sorry there is nothing more we can do if you are being so vague.

@Charlieface ... on Friday, I re-analysed the recompile that I'd put in place and found I marked the wrong stored procedure! I corrected it, the re-indexing ran on Saturday and so far, it's been running fine and I haven't had to adjust any settings ... so many thanks for all your help :)

It's really hard to say without further information regarding query plans, which for some reason you refuse to give us.
But it looks like all your ARITHABORT statement is doing is causing a recompile, because the code has changed. This in turn seems to make it up fresh statistics information.
You can do this much more easily by adding the following statement to the end of your indexing job:
EXEC sp_recompile N'dbo.YourProcName';


Just to add Charieface's good answer, it frequently takes a whole lot less time and resources to recompile it every time rather than have to detect and decide on something that causes some pretty nasty problems if it does go haywire.  I'll also add that the OP should take the time to figure out if the index maintenance is actually helping or not.  If not, stop it... especially since most people also don't take the time to figure out how to do it correctly.

@Charliface, I wasn't being intentionally obstructive, I just never saw your comment about  actually supplying that kind of information.
